# Does the Chrome browser development tools respect style changes specifying !important?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm doing a bit of CSS troubleshooting and, as you can imagine, I'm having a tough time getting a div to style the way I want it too.  In Chrome, I've opened the development window and I've selected my element to inspect the style settings.

I need to do a quick visual test of some of my changes from within a specific selector.  Note, I'm not looking to declare a temporary, specific value for the element.

I've found the selector, and the respective CSS property and as I knew, it is crossed out because a CSS definition of higher precedence is overriding it.  However, for my test I added `!important` after the property value but it did not update my element and remained crossed out.

We have some very complex CSS.  There is a chance that it's somehow being overridden but I wanted to be sure-- in Chrome browser, within the development window, if you override a style specified for an object, adding `!important` should it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the Chrome browser development tools respect style changes specifying !important?

Yes it does respect the specificity.

You can however test the specificity of your rule before using it in the devtools (or anyplace for that matter) [**here**](http://specificity.keegan.st/)